# Launch an app as soon as Desktop environment is launched

Tags: unity, xorg, desktop-environments, auto-login, kiosk

Is it possible to launch an app with a GUI (in my case it's a Python script using wxPython for GUI) **as soon as possible when computer is powered on / when Desktop environment is launched**?

And, if possible, without any display of desktop background before, no desktop environment loading screen before, I would like that my app is the first thing displayed, like in a kiosk.

*Note1: I could disable the DE, and just run X and my app, but I'd prefer to keep a DE launched, but just not show it at all before my app is launched. Then if the user closes the app, it's good that the Desktop is there*

*Note2: I use the default Ubuntu desktop environment (is it called Unity?)*

Comment: Simply run the app with a try-except on log in (Using Startup Applications)& make it run full screen. As long as the desktop is not ready, it will break, retrying until the desktop is ready. How do you call the window in your script?

Comment: @JacobVlijm with `python myscript.py`. Can you post an answer with the example config you would use? I would like to have nothing displayed except my app, i.e. no Linux loading message (if possible, I would even turn BIOS display off on startup!),  it's a kiosk computer

Answer (score 2):

Open "System Settings" and then click on "Startup and Shutdown" under "Workspace". There you should be able to add applications or scripts to be started on login.